# jQuery DOM ready and JavaScript execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

How does the following snipped work?

```
$((function () {
    alert('I''m ready!')
}()));
```

As I get it, it:

1. executes jQuery .ready() - which gets fired only after DOM is loaded
2. it is wrapped to stay anonymous (is there a point if it's passed to $ anyway?)
3. function is defined and executed immediately

Comment: this is documented here http://api.jquery.com/ready/ and here http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/  primarily `If .ready() is called after the DOM has been initialized, the new handler passed in will be executed immediately.`

Comment: As I get those 3 points correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't create a document ready handler. [jQuery's `$()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) does different things depending on what you pass to it, and in this case you're passing `undefined`.

The inner anonymous function expression:

```
(function () {
    alert('I''m ready!')
}())
```

is executed *immediately* because of the `()` after it, and then its return value is passed to `$()` - it doesn't explicitly return anything, so the return is `undefined` (as mentioned above).

If you actually want to do that alert after the document is ready remove the `()` like so:

```
$(function () {
    alert('I''m ready!')
});
```

Comment: I don't think there should be an immediate invokation.

Comment: @ZenMaster: Correct. There shouldn't be, but there is in the OP's code, which is what nnnnnn is pointing out.

Comment: So how to execute anonymous function after DOM ready? / nnnnnn's edid answered that.

Comment: @undefined well, that's what you normally do when you go `$(function() {...});` - you execetue an anonymous function after the DOM is ready.

Comment: @ZenMaster Yes, of course, I thought he/she wants to use a self-invoking function within the ready handler.

Answer (score 4):

> How does the following snipped work?

Arguably, it doesn't.

Let's separate the two things that code is doing, using an intermediate variable:

```
// First
var x = (function () {
    alert('I''m ready!')
}());

// Then:
$(x);
```

The first bit defines a function **and calls it immediately**, causing the `alert` to be shown. The return value from the function call is stored in `x`. Since the function doesn't return anything, the result of calling it is `undefined.`

The second bit then calls jQuery's `$` function passing in `undefined`, which basically won't do anything.

You probably meant this:

```
$(function () {
    alert('I''m ready!')
});
```

Note that there is no `()` after the function calling it. That breaks down like this:

```
// First
var x = function () {
    alert('I''m ready!')
};

// Then:
$(x);
```

*Here* what happens is that the function is defined and *not* called; a reference to the function is stored in `x`.

Then we call `$` and pass in that function reference, which is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(x)`.

So this code:

```
$(function () {
    alert('I''m ready!')
});
```

First defines a function (without calling it), and then passes a reference to that function into `$`.

Later, when the DOM is ready, jQuery will call that function.

Answer (score -3):

```
$(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

is shorthand for for

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

see this http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: This does not answer the question OP has `How does the following snipped work?` Additionaly if the code was actually intended to pass the result of an IIFE this answer is of no use.

Comment: It's not an answer. -1